# Java string to JSON and vice versa

Tags: java, string, json, org.json

I am looking for a way to convert a String to a JSON object and vice versa.

I have a String with JSON notation as value. I need to convert this value to JSON object in order to get specific data out of the JSON objects. Afterwarts, i need to convert a specific JSON object (attribute) to an JAVA attribute.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I know Java has the `import org.json.JSONObject;` which enables me to create JSONObjects, but i cannot figure out how to convert my JSON String to a JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JSONObject constructor

```
public JSONObject(java.lang.String source) throws JSONException
```

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the string:
[How to Parse JSON in Java](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/)

Comment: That's for the `net.sf.json` library, not `org.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) you can do something like

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyObject result = mapper.readValue( myString, MyObject.class );
```

If you don't have an object mapping, you can just map it to a class instead.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> mymap = mapper.readValue( myString, Map.class );
```

If you don't want to use Jackson, you can look at [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), which is equally as intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\employee.json"), employee);

   // display to console
   Object json = objectMapper.readValue(
     objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employee), Object.class);

   System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
     .writeValueAsString(json));
```

Answer (score -1):

[Read the documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).

```
String json = ....
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

Comment: HTTP 404 for your link.